# problem with symbol ^, kerkis-font and texttt

Tags: typewriter

I want to write something like this `SomeCode^MoreCode`, so I wrote the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}


\begin{document}

\textlatin{\texttt{SomeCode\^{}MoreCode}}

\textlatin{Some text \^{} more text}

\end{document}
```

*The problem is that I don't get the symbol **^** when it is in `texttt{}`. If I delete kerkis-font, everything is OK*.

[image]

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the preamble and check.

Comment: @Tanvir ,thanks a lot! Problem solved! How can I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: I felt this being a simple thing, so I just add the answer as a comment. You may add an update to your question, mentioning the answer.

Comment: do you really want `\^{}` a hat accent over nothing, why not use `^` which is `\textasciicircum`

Comment: @Tanvir , I 've been to late for that... I marked as an answer David's answer. Thank's for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need T1 encoding to get a larger range of characters, but also I think you want the character `^` which you can get with `\textasciiicircum` or `\verb` not a circumflex accent over nothing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\textlatin{\texttt{SomeCode\^{}MoreCode}}

\textlatin{Some text \^{} more text}


\textlatin{\texttt{SomeCode\textasciicircum{}MoreCode}}

\textlatin{Some text \textasciicircum{} more text}

\begin{otherlanguage}{english} \verb|SomeCode^MoreCode| \end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! You gave me many advises! I had problem with `verb`, but now I know what to do!

Answer (score 2):

For unknown reasons, the developers of the Kerkis fonts released them with a nonstandard version of the OT1 encoding.

Indeed, in `kerkis.sty` we find

```latex
\DeclareTextAccent{\`}{OT1}{30}
\DeclareTextAccent{\'}{OT1}{180}
\DeclareTextAccent{\^}{OT1}{25}
```

and other similar declarations. They work for Kerkis, but break other fonts that conform to the OT1 standard, in particular the Courier font that `kerkis.sty` declares as the monospaced font with

```
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

To the contrary, the T1 encoded Kerkis fonts follow the standard.

If you only use the serif and sans serif Kerkis fonts, OT1 is good; otherwise, always remember to do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in your documents using Kerkis.

Comment: thank you very much!  Many of greek fonts have problems. That's sad, because GFS-fonts are very beautiful: https://tinyurl.com/yxpgmc7m or https://tinyurl.com/y6c5uuky